# Usage of GtkFixed: inner widget ignores the coordinates

Tags: c, gtk2

I'm trying to move a GtkFrame, inside a GtkFixed, to the left. Original code below

```
frm_2 = gtk_frame_new (NULL);
gtk_widget_show (frm_2);
gtk_fixed_put (GTK_FIXED (fixed1), frm_2, 160, 16);
gtk_widget_set_size_request (frm_2, 1105, 264);
gtk_frame_set_shadow_type (GTK_FRAME (frm_2), GTK_SHADOW_ETCHED_OUT);

fixed3 = gtk_fixed_new ();
gtk_widget_show (fixed3);
gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (frm_2), fixed3 );

frm_1_frm_2 = gtk_frame_new (NULL);
gtk_widget_show (frm_1_frm_2);
gtk_fixed_put (GTK_FIXED (fixed3), frm_1_frm_2, 6, 8); // <-- THIS
gtk_widget_set_size_request (frm_1_frm_2, 250, 224);
gtk_frame_set_shadow_type (GTK_FRAME (frm_1_frm_2), GTK_SHADOW_ETCHED_OUT);
```

I tried with

```
gtk_fixed_put (GTK_FIXED (fixed3), frm_1_frm_2, 0, 8);
```

And with

```
gtk_fixed_put (GTK_FIXED (fixed3), frm_1_frm_2, 50, 8);
```

In all cases, the result its the same: The GtkFrame position looks unchanged, it behaves the same way as the first code snippet.

The complete hierarchy of the widgets is:

```
GtkWindow( GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL )
|
+-GtkFixed fixed1
| |
| +-GtkFrame
|
+-GtkFrame frm_2
    |
    +-GtkFixed fixed3
      |
      +-GtkFrame frm_1_frm_2
      |
      +-GtkFrame another frame
...
```

The Gtk version is:

> ls libgtk*
>   libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0.2400.23

1. What am I doing wrong ?
2. How do I solve it?

<sub>Sorry for my bad english.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

#1 Please provide a Minimum Working Example of what you observe. Fortunately from what you have put up I haven't had to do much work in order to paste it in to an existing codebase and get it to build but there is a chance that the problem is outside of the code you have posted (even if only indirectly). I have tried out your code and the inner widget displays as it is tasked to do (different positions for different x values).

#2 Don't ever ever ever use GtkFixed. I know there are a lot of dogmatic coding guidelines (personally I like goto) but this one has merit. Gtk sits above a display manager which in turn will sit above a backend like x11 quartz or wayland. Gtk doesn't say where widgets should go. That's not its job. It can only advise.

You may very well have the situation where Gtk walks into the office, says "I want this that and the other and have it on my desk by the close of business".

Gdk says "sure thing boss".

When he's out of the room x11 says "doesn't he know that'll break accessibility?" or "what good is a close button that isn't even placed within the bounds of the screen?" or even "Computer says no".

"Just put it where you think is best and I'll find a way to obfuscating the report."

"obfa-what?"

"exactly"

In summary your display manager will make a lot of decision you can't (largely because you shouldn't) control. This may be why your widget isn't where you want. Try to avoid relying on GtkFixed and instead use other containers and add padding and spacing as you feel necessary to get a similar effect. Just don't use GtkFixed. It is evil. UI developers will be sending you hate mail for years to come. Don't use GtkFixed. Seriously don't do it. Life is a beautiful thing to be appreciated and cherished for all its goodness. Don't use GtkFixed. You'll spend months with your tail between your legs like when my dog got fixed. Don't use GtkFixed.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the inconvenience. These code it's a *bad gift* from my work. Finally I solved it ... the problem is complex and it is not easy to reproduce. We use a hash to link vars with identifiers. In another file, the frames are moved in response to external events ... I'm sorry for the bad question. ...